# I keep getting a 404 error with sveltekit

Tags: routes, http-status-code-404, svelte, server-side-rendering, sveltekit

I keep getting a 404 error when routing to this page,How do i fix it Here is a screenshot of my project
[image: screenshot of my project]

I have tried everything i know so far to fix this

Answer (score 1):

That is not how routes work, please [read the docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing).

Every route has its own folder and its own `+page`, so you need `src/routes/next/+page.svelte` for the `/next` route.